# How sshexec works internally

Tags: java, ssh

I only know that sshexec is used to run a command on a remote computer but I am trying to know a bit more about how sshexec works internally. Could anyone tell me??

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "sshexec"? I'm not aware of a program with that specific name.

Comment: It's not a program, it's more like a package.                                                                        This is how its used:                                                                                ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("ipAddress", "systemUserName", "password");

        SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
        ssh.connect();
        CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("your linux command");
        Result res = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
               
        ssh.disconnect();

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to include tags for the programming language that you're using, then.

Comment: I'm using Java programming language. I have added java tag now.